# Table column not updated after Alter Table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add a column to a table in case the column doesn't exist,but SQLite doesn't seem to update the column list in Android

currently i'm using:

```
DB.execSQL("alter table "+table_name+" add column "+column_name+" text");
DB.rawQuery("select * from "+table_name+" limit 1",null).getColumnNames();
```

but the string list returned from "getColumnNames" does not contain the column I just created, so when I check again for the same column, it understands the column doesn't exist and tries to create it again, which causes a "duplicated column" exception

Thanks in advance for any help,this is my first question in SO :)

Comment: Did you put your code in onUpgrade? And did you increase the database version?

Comment: No and no. should I?

Comment: Yes, when you increase the database version, on next launch the method onUpgrade will be called. There you run the command to alter the table.

Comment: Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the database number, which will call onUpgrade on your next app launch. In your onUpgrade method, you run the SQLite command to alter the table.

See [here](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to discard the result of the first query after the "alter table" command and use the result of a second query. It worked for me.